# Check VAT Number at VIES with classic ASP + SOAP

Tags: soap, asp-classic

I'm trying to check European VAT Number at VIES via Webservice:

with my poor knowledge I built the following routine:

```
<%
    strEnvelope="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:urn=""urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types"">"
    strEnvelope=strEnvelope&"<soapenv:Header/>"
    strEnvelope=strEnvelope&"<soapenv:Body>"
    strEnvelope=strEnvelope&"<urn:checkVat>"
    strEnvelope=strEnvelope&"<urn:countryCode>DE</urn:countryCode>"
    strEnvelope=strEnvelope&"<urn:vatNumber>247856515</urn:vatNumber>"
    strEnvelope=strEnvelope&"</urn:checkVat>"
    strEnvelope=strEnvelope&"</soapenv:Body>"
    strEnvelope=strEnvelope&"</soapenv:Envelope>"



    set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    objHTTP.open "post", "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPMethodName", "checkVat"
    objHTTP.send strEnvelope
    strReturn = objHTTP.responseBody
    response.write strReturn
%>
```

but I got this answer

```
    çŒ¼æ…¯ã©°æ¹…æ•¶æ½¬æ•°ç  æ±­ç®çŒºæ…¯ãµ°æ ¢ç‘´ã©°â¼¯æ³æ•¨æ…­â¹³æµ¸ç¬æ…¯â¹°ç‰¯â½§æ½³ç¡æ”¯ç™®æ±¥ç¯â½¥ã¸¢çŒ¼æ…¯ã©°æ½‚ç¥¤ã°¾æ¡£æ¥å™«ç‘¡æ•’ç³æ¹¯æ•³ç  æ±­ç®âˆ½ç‰µã©®æ¥æ”®ç‰µç¯â¹¡ç•¥çºç¡¡æ‘µç˜ºæ•©ã©³æ•³ç™²æ©ç¥æŒºæ•¨æ­£æ…–ã©´ç¥´æ•°â‰³ã°¾æ½£æ¹µç‰´ä¹æ‘¯ã¹¥ä•„â¼¼æ½£æ¹µç‰´ä¹æ‘¯ã¹¥ç˜¼ç‘¡ç•Žæ‰­ç‰¥ãˆ¾ãœ´ã”¸ã”¶ã”±â¼¼æ…¶ä¹´æµµæ•¢ã¹²çˆ¼ç…¥æ•µç‘³æ…„æ•´ãˆ¾ã„°â´·ãœ°ã„­â¬µãˆ°ã€ºã°°çˆ¯ç…¥æ•µç‘³æ…„æ•´ã°¾æ…¶æ¥¬ã¹¤ç‰´æ•µâ¼¼æ…¶æ¥¬ã¹¤æ¸¼æµ¡ã¹¥â´­ã°­æ¸¯æµ¡ã¹¥æ„¼æ‘¤æ•²ç³â´¾â´­â¼¼æ‘¡ç‰¤ç¥ã¹³â¼¼æ¡£æ¥å™«ç‘¡æ•’ç³æ¹¯æ•³ã°¾çŒ¯æ…¯ã©°æ½‚ç¥¤ã°¾çŒ¯æ…¯ã©°æ¹…æ•¶æ½¬æ•°> Ã§Å’Â¼Ã¦â€¦Â¯Ã£Â©Â°Ã¦Â¹â€¦Ã¦â€¢Â¶Ã¦Â½Â¬Ã¦â€¢Â°Ã§ Ã¦Â±Â­Ã§ÂÂ®Ã§Å’ÂºÃ¦â€¦Â¯Ã£ÂµÂ°Ã¦ Â¢Ã§â€˜Â´Ã£Â©Â°Ã¢Â¼Â¯Ã¦ÂÂ³Ã¦â€¢Â¨Ã¦â€¦Â­Ã¢Â¹Â³Ã¦ÂµÂ¸Ã§ÂÂ¬Ã¦â€¦Â¯Ã¢Â¹Â°Ã§â€°Â¯Ã¢Â½Â§Ã¦Â½Â³Ã§ÂÂ¡Ã¦â€Â¯Ã§â„¢Â®Ã¦Â±Â¥Ã§ÂÂ¯Ã¢Â½Â¥Ã£Â¸Â¢Ã§Å’Â¼Ã¦â€¦Â¯Ã£Â©Â°Ã¦Â½â€šÃ§Â¥Â¤Ã£Â°Â¾Ã¦Â¡Â£Ã¦ÂÂ¥Ã¥â„¢Â«Ã§â€˜Â¡Ã¦â€¢â€™Ã§ÂÂ³Ã¦Â¹Â¯Ã¦â€¢Â³Ã§ Ã¦Â±Â­Ã§ÂÂ®Ã¢Ë†Â½Ã§â€°ÂµÃ£Â©Â®Ã¦ÂÂ¥Ã¦â€Â®Ã§â€°ÂµÃ§ÂÂ¯Ã¢Â¹Â¡Ã§â€¢Â¥Ã§ÂÂºÃ§Â¡Â¡Ã¦â€˜ÂµÃ§ËœÂºÃ¦â€¢Â©Ã£Â©Â³Ã¦â€¢Â³Ã§â„¢Â²Ã¦ÂÂ©Ã§ÂÂ¥Ã¦Å’ÂºÃ¦â€¢Â¨Ã¦Â­Â£Ã¦â€¦â€“Ã£Â©Â´Ã§Â¥Â´Ã¦â€¢Â°Ã¢â€°Â³Ã£Â°Â¾Ã¦Â½Â£Ã¦Â¹ÂµÃ§â€°Â´Ã¤ÂÂ¹Ã¦â€˜Â¯Ã£Â¹Â¥Ã¤â€¢â€žÃ¢Â¼Â¼Ã¦Â½Â£Ã¦Â¹ÂµÃ§â€°Â´Ã¤ÂÂ¹Ã¦â€˜Â¯Ã£Â¹Â¥Ã§ËœÂ¼Ã§â€˜Â¡Ã§â€¢Å½Ã¦â€°Â­Ã§â€°Â¥Ã£Ë†Â¾Ã£Å“Â´Ã£â€Â¸Ã£â€Â¶Ã£â€Â±Ã¢Â¼Â¼Ã¦â€¦Â¶Ã¤Â¹Â´Ã¦ÂµÂµÃ¦â€¢Â¢Ã£Â¹Â²Ã§Ë†Â¼Ã§â€¦Â¥Ã¦â€¢ÂµÃ§â€˜Â³Ã¦â€¦â€žÃ¦â€¢Â´Ã£Ë†Â¾Ã£â€žÂ°Ã¢Â´Â·Ã£Å“Â°Ã£â€žÂ­Ã¢Â¬ÂµÃ£Ë†Â°Ã£â‚¬ÂºÃ£Â°Â°Ã§Ë†Â¯Ã§â€¦Â¥Ã¦â€¢ÂµÃ§â€˜Â³Ã¦â€¦â€žÃ¦â€¢Â´Ã£Â°Â¾Ã¦â€¦Â¶Ã¦Â¥Â¬Ã£Â¹Â¤Ã§â€°Â´Ã¦â€¢ÂµÃ¢Â¼Â¼Ã¦â€¦Â¶Ã¦Â¥Â¬Ã£Â¹Â¤Ã¦Â¸Â¼Ã¦ÂµÂ¡Ã£Â¹Â¥Ã¢Â´Â­Ã£Â°Â­Ã¦Â¸Â¯Ã¦ÂµÂ¡Ã£Â¹Â¥Ã¦â€žÂ¼Ã¦â€˜Â¤Ã¦â€¢Â²Ã§ÂÂ³Ã¢Â´Â¾Ã¢Â´Â­Ã¢Â¼Â¼Ã¦â€˜Â¡Ã§â€°Â¤Ã§ÂÂ¥Ã£Â¹Â³Ã¢Â¼Â¼Ã¦Â¡Â£Ã¦ÂÂ¥Ã¥â„¢Â«Ã§â€˜Â¡Ã¦â€¢â€™Ã§ÂÂ³Ã¦Â¹Â¯Ã¦â€¢Â³Ã£Â°Â¾Ã§Å’Â¯Ã¦â€¦Â¯Ã£Â©Â°Ã¦Â½â€šÃ§Â¥Â¤Ã£Â°Â¾Ã§Å’Â¯Ã¦â€¦Â¯Ã£Â©Â°Ã¦Â¹â€¦Ã¦â€¢Â¶Ã¦Â½Â¬Ã¦â€¢Â°>
```

can give some hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text representation of the response is in the `responseText` property, so:

```
  strReturn = objHTTP.responseText
```